# Not able to get file when i m try to use export

Tags: magento2

Using magneto(2.3.3)
When try to Export csv file then getting message 
**"Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon"**
how long i have to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command then check in admin

> php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor

you will get download option

[image]

Comment: Thank you. it's work

Comment: great can you accept my answer ?

Comment: yes. solve my problem thank you