# Bulk Export Magneto 2 product PSV

Tags: magento2.3, csv, importexport

I'm using Magento 2.3.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm having 141 000 products that I want to export to a CSV file. Nothing happens when I try to export. It just says

> Message is added to the queue, wait to get your file soon

I tried to check the export process but the computer thinks forever.
[Not able to get file when i m try to use export](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295953/not-able-to-get-file-when-i-m-try-to-use-export)

Is there another way to export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix this way..

Open below file

> vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php

and replace below function

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(ExportModel::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::class);
            $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());
            $this->sessionManager->writeClose();

            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                $model->getContentType()
            );

            /** @var ExportInfoFactory $dataObject */
            $dataObject = $this->exportInfoFactory->create(
                $params['file_format'],
                $params['entity'],
                $params['export_filter']
            );

            $this->messagePublisher->publish('import_export.export', $dataObject);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon')
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

**Please don't forget to clear cache after change in files**

Comment: Hi! I don't have that folder path. I have module-inventory-import-export. Am I missing some folders?

Comment: @NicklasGilbertsson this path: vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php

Comment: Hi thanks! I seems that those files doesn't exist in this project.

Comment: @NicklasGilbertsson i think you missed because this file available in all version(https://prnt.sc/rdmk80)

Comment: It works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

First run the commands :-

If your var/importexportxxx file is blank try;

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23450

Other Second : -

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```